# custom ng-repeat with conditional ng-class

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I would like "translate" JSON to icon list:

```
"score": [
{
  "idgroup": 0,
  "value": 1
},
{
  "idgroup": 1,
  "value": 0
},
{
  "idgroup": 2,
  "value": 0
}
]
```

to:

```
<ul>
<li class="icon-active-profil"/><li class="icon-profil"/><li class="icon-profil"/>
</ul>
<ul>
<li class="icon-profil"/><li class="icon-profil"/><li class="icon-profil"/>
</ul>
<ul>
<li class="icon-profil"/><li class="icon-profil"/><li class="icon-profil"/>
</ul>
```

Each line has 3 icons and default class is **icon-profil**. In the example, the first item has only one active icon (**icon-active-profil**). Depends score.value

**update : **

```
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="n in [0,1,2]" ng-class="{'icon-fessier-active':scores[1].value>0}" class="icon-fessier icon-profil"/>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="n in [0,1,2]" ng-class="{'icon-stretch-active':scores[2].value>0}" class="icon-stretch icon-profil"/>
        </ul>
```

Result: I have three times the same class, I dont see what is the good approach

Comment: Have you tried anything? What's the specific problem you're facing?

Comment: Of course yes ! I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li ng-repeat="n in [0,1,2]" ng-class="{'icon-fessier-active':scores[1].value>0}" class="icon-fessier icon-profil"/>
```

You're not using `n` anywhere in your ng-class. So all the classes are identical.

If I understand correctly, what you want is `'icon-fessier-active'` to be present if the score value is equal to `n`, so

```
<li ng-repeat="n in [0,1,2]" ng-class="{'icon-fessier-active':scores[1].value === n}" class="icon-fessier icon-profil"/>
```

Comment: It was not really the goal of the n (initially just to repeat 3 times) but it work !!  just change the operator to >= :  <br/> <li ng-repeat="n in [1,2,3]" ng-class="{'icon-fessier-active':scores[1].value >= n}" class="icon-fessier icon-profil"/>

Comment: You rules !! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul ng-repeat="score in scores">
  <li ng-class="score.value ? 'icon-active-profil' : 'icon-active'">
  <li class="icon-profil"/>
  <li class="icon-profil"/>
</ul>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on [so]. Please explain a bit what is going on. Thanks.